# firestore.Timestamp import is undefined in firebase-admin@11

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

In `firebase-admin@10` I used to retrieve the document data using this approach:

```
const userRef = await firestore()
  .collection('users')
  .withConverter(UserConverter)
  .doc(userId)
  .get();

const userData = userRef.data();
```

But recently I upgraded to `firebase-admin@11` and now calling `userRef.data()` throws an error:

> TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object`.

I tried downgrading to version 10 - it solved the issue. But I'd like to know what is the right solution in the latest version - I couldn't find it.

Upd. I've found the source of the problem: in my `UserConverter` I have such a check:

```
import { firestore } from "firebase-admin";
import { DateTime } from "luxon";
import { UserEntity } from "../entities";

export class UserEntityConverter implements firestore.FirestoreDataConverter<UserEntity> {
  toFirestore(modelObject: UserEntity): firestore.DocumentData;
  toFirestore(modelObject: Partial<UserEntity>, options: firestore.SetOptions): firestore.DocumentData;
  toFirestore(modelObject: UserEntity | Partial<UserEntity>, options?: firestore.SetOptions): firestore.DocumentData {
    return {
      balance: modelObject.balance,
      lastLoggedAt: modelObject.lastLoggedAt?.toJSDate() || null,
    };
  }

  fromFirestore(snapshot: firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot<firestore.DocumentData>): UserEntity {
  const data = snapshot.data();

  userEntity.balance = snapshot.balance;

  const lastLoggedAtData = data.lastLoggedAt;
  // this is where it breaks now: `firestore.Timestamp === undefined`
  if (lastLoggedAtData && lastLoggedAtData instanceof firestore.Timestamp) {
    userEntity.collectedRewardAt = DateTime.fromMillis(collectedRewardAtData.toMillis());
  }
}
```

The source of the problem is `firestore.Timestamp` - it's `undefined` now for some reason (though it's still present in the typings).

Comment: 11 had a bunch of [documented breaking changes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node#version_1100_-_16_june_2022), including an update to the underlying Cloud Firestore SDK it uses.  Might want to dig into those to figure out what happened.  It also might help if you show the entire code sample, including `UserConverter`, so we can duplicate what you did.

Comment: @DougStevenson You were right: the problem was in my converter. I updated my question and specifically pointed to the problem - it's `firestore.Timestamp === undefined` (and the typings are misleading about it still being there).

Comment: Now the problem is that we can't see how you imported `firestore`, so we still can't duplicate the issue the way you are observing it..  On Stack Overflow, it's always a good idea to [provide complete minimal code that reproduces the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @DougStevenson Sorry about that. I updated the snippet in my question once again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the Firestore team is on the way to make the 2nd Gen Firestore Admin SDK to support 1st Gen like the [latest Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/2nd-gen-upgrade):

> Make sure you're using at least Firebase CLI version 12.00 and
> firebase-functions version 4.3.0. Any newer version will support 2nd
> gen **as well as 1st gen**.

But the `firebase-admin@11` as you mentioned has no backward compatibility like the Firebase Functions. However, you still can use the `CommonJS require()` as shown below, but all your `firestore.Timestamp`, `firestore.FieldValue` blah blah blah need to use the following approach:

```
const { getFirestore, Timestamp, FieldValue, Transaction } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');
```

Then you can do like this:

```
// No more firestore.Timestamp
if (lastLoggedAtData && lastLoggedAtData instanceof Timestamp) {
    userEntity.collectedRewardAt = DateTime.fromMillis(collectedRewardAtData.toMillis());
  }
```

But the global find and replace can be tedious though.